# CDI behaviour on classes with same canonical name

Tags: classloader, cdi, java-ee-7

For some simple classes, it happens that I use the class loading to overwrite a class in a jar file (eg. to fix a bug). I do this by creating an identical class (same package, same name) in my application, resulting in this class being used instead of the one in the jar.
Anyway, this works well.

However, with CDI, it's a different story. When the bean is @Named , Weld tells me the bean name is ambiguous. I'm currently using @Named with the same name on my own definition, but this results in the problem.

Is there a way how to avoid this conflict and retain the duplicated classes?

Comment: To clarify - you want to have **both classes** loaded? With any injection framework, what *will cause problems*. Not only for `@Named` but a simple `@Inject` as well - because at that moment, you will have two identical and always fitting beans for injection. How do you handle that?

Comment: Well, one specializes the other, so I would presume that the specialized version takes precedence?

Comment: Well, specialization in CDI (if we talk about `@Specializes`) works the way it **disables** the original bean in favor of the specializing one. E.g. the previous one will no longer be eligible for injection. Also, with CDI specialization, **bean name is inherited** - there should be no need to declare the name again. If you had this problem even without it, then it seems you don't really use specialization because the bean somehow gets picked up.

Comment: I was also thinking you might be able to resolve this via extension - there you could disable (or rather veto) the original beans, given you have a way to distinguish them from the newly added ones.

Comment: I found out that my specialized annotations did not get discovered without an empty beans.xml . Adding that fixes things. Not sure why though, as I'm running Wildfly10 on Java8. (not the canonical naming issue btw, I stepped away from that thing in relation to CDI)

Comment: Because without `beans.xml` CDI uses the **annotated** discovery mode which means only classes with [`bean defining annotation`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) (e.g. BDA) will be picked up. OTOH with empty `beans.xml` you are using **all** discovery mode, where even not annotated classes will be picked up (as dependent scoped beans). That being said `@Specializes` is not amongst BDA which is why I guess it did not work.